# Getting the last item from a Drupal db_fetch_object

Tags: drupal

What's the best way to do this?  I've been falling back onto doing a while() loop over the result and snagging the last one as it goes by, but this seems a little, um, inelegant.  D7 offers some help here, but is there any advice out there for D6?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not reverse the order of your query and limit to 1 and get that?

Something like:

`$result = db_query_range("SELECT * FROM {table} ORDER BY field DESC", 0, 1)`;

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql.inc/function/db_query_range/6

Comment: Thx; good idea, but not quite. A better problem statement: I've got a table of time-stamped items, and I want to get the N most recent items in the table. However, there could be ties -- if I'm looking for 5 items, the 6th item could have the same time as #5. So, my plan was to get the top five, get the timestamp of the 5th, and then redo the query to get all the items with timestamps up to that value (in this case, getting the 6th item). Thus my possibly kludgy way above, which at least seems to be working. But now @rimian has me worried about the transactional aspects of all this. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In general case (no engine tips like for mysql), use:

```
$query = 'SELECT nid, title from {node} WHERE type="page"';
$query_count = 'SELECT count(*) from {node} WHERE type="page"';
$count = db_result(db_query($query_count)); // $query_count
$last_record = db_fetch_object(db_query_range($query, $count-1, 1));
```

If query use ordering, just use "counter-ordering":

```
$query = 'SELECT nid, title from {node} WHERE type="page" ORDER BY nid ASC';
// ...
$counterquery = 'SELECT nid, title from {node} WHERE type="page" ORDER BY nid DESC LIMIT 0,1';
$last_record = db_fetch_object(db_query($counterquery));
```

Comment: What if someone created another node while this was happening? It's not transactional.

Comment: Then just look second example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [db_last_insert_id()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql-common.inc/function/db_last_insert_id/6)